# iOS Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

My app will allow users to create a registration form and it will be displayed using a UITableView. I'm having trouble updating the UITableView. Just to explain a bit what is going on, I have 2 scenes. The 1st scenes displays the created questions and the 2nd scene allows the user to create a question. The 1st scene segues to the 2nd, and then the 2nd scene unwind segues to the 1st seen with the question data. Here's my code.

1st scene:

```
@IBOutlet var tableViewObject: UITableView!
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

// code for creating tableView
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.questionsArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = self.questionsArray[indexPath.row].Label
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

}
@IBAction func segueToView(sender: AnyObject) {

}

@IBAction func cancelToSecondViewController(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
}

@IBAction func saveQuestion(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let CreateQuestion = segue.sourceViewController as? createQuestion {

        if (CreateQuestion.flag == 0) {
           let textinput = CreateQuestion.newInputQuestion
            questionsArray.append(textinput)
        }

        else {
            let multichoice = CreateQuestion.newMultiQuestion
            questionsArray.append(multichoice)
        }

        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: questionsArray.count-1, inSection: 0)
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    }
}
```

2nd scene:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SaveQuestion" {
        if (questionType.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
            newInputQuestion = textInput(placeHolder: inputQuestionHint.text!, Label: inputQuestionTitle.text!, required: required.selectedSegmentIndex)
            flag = 0
        }

        else {
            var arrayOfAnswers = [String]()

            for (var i = 0; i < numAnswers.selectedSegmentIndex + 1; i++) {
                arrayOfAnswers.append(numAnswersArray[i].text!)
            }

            newMultiQuestion = multiChoice(answers: arrayOfAnswers, Label: multiQuestionTitle.text!, required: required.selectedSegmentIndex)
            flag = 1
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I try to create a question:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

It highlights the following line:

> tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)

Comment: Actually I discovered through other means of testing that declaring it as type Question works. This is not the cause of my error that has to do with updating the array so I might edit this question.

Comment: where is `tableView` declared?

Comment: In the 1st scene. I'll edit my post with the tableview code

Comment: You posted the tableview delegate functions, but not the location where `tableView` is declared. Is there a line that looks something like this: `@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!`?

Comment: The very first line of the code says that!

Comment: Something is wrong in interface builder. Check your outlet connections and make sure they are configured correctly. Make sure in your storyboard that you have set the view controller's class for your subclass of `UIViewController`. `tableView` is `nil`, and since it is configured by interface builder, that is where the problem is.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this line, "Make sure in your storyboard that you have set the view controller's class for your subclass of UIViewController."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tableView` is `nil`. Since it is an `@IBOutlet` that is configured by interface builder, something is wrong with how you configured it in interface builder.

The most likely culprit is that you did not set the class for your view controller in the identity inspector.

Go to interface builder and make sure the utilities pane is open. Open the identity inspector in the utilities pane. Near the top is a place for you to enter the class name of your custom view controller. So if your view controller is called `MyViewController`, make sure to enter `MyViewController` into that field.

If that doesn't work, then the `@IBOutlet` isn't configured properly. Check your connections, and then double check them.

Comment: So I got it working, and honestly I'm not sure what I did, but your comments led me in the right direction. Thank you for your help.